# Freshly installed elementary OS Freya missing on boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader, elementary-os

In my laptop right now I have two operating systems: Windows 8 and Ubuntu. I also had a third one I installed in the past but never used it: elementary OS Luna.

I saw elementary OS finally released a stable version, Freya, so I decided to give it a try.

So I installed Freya in the partition where Luna used to be. Everything went right; I restarted the computer and unplugged the boot USB – and there was no elementary OS Freya in any boot menu. I say "any" boot menu because there are two: first the one for Windows 8 pops up, with this OS as its only option, and if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, GRUB pops up, with Ubuntu, elementary OS Luna and two more options. After installing Freya it still showed the old Luna, and when selecting this option the computer just restarts and there we go again with the boot menus.

I think I am messing up with the partitions and GRUB. Let me show you quickly what my partition table looks like:

```
/dev/sda
    free space 1 MB
    /dev/sda3/ biosgrub 9 MB
    /dev/sda1 ntfs 619 MB
    /dev/sda2 efi 314 MB Windows Boot Manager
    /dev/sda4 ntfs 241321 MB
    /dev/sda9 fat32 155301 MB
    /dev/sda8 ext4 30720 MB elementary OS Freya(0.3)
    free space 0 MB
    /dev/sda7 swap 2047
    /dev/sda6 ext4 51199 MB Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (14.04)
    /dev/sda5 ntfs 18572 MB
    free space 0 MB
```

As you can see, `/dev/sda8` was formatted; it's where Freya was installed. By the way, do I need to define another swap partition for Elementary? Or it will use the same one Ubuntu does?

For the "boot loader installation device location" I chose `/dev/sda8`. Maybe this is the problem: I chose that instead of just `/dev/sda`. Since I am not entirely sure what this does, I am afraid of the possibility that it will install the OS in the whole hard disk so I would lose everything else. Or in the other way I can look at it, if I had chosen `/dev/sda` instead that means it will create a partition for the boot loader and no problem.

So is there any way I can fix this? Or just try reinstalling Elementary? Please tell me with details which partitions I should choose.

P.D. Sorry for the formatting of the partition table, but I am typing this from a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you should update the existing **GRUB** boot loader.

The existing **GRUB** boot loader may have been installed to `/dev/sda6` or, likely `/dev/sda3 biosgrub 9 MB`? Anyway, I am guessing that your first Linux distribution was Ubuntu.

Therefore, do the following steps.

**Step 1:** Boot and login to Ubuntu 14.04 (or your first Linux distro)

**Step 2:** Open **Terminal**, and run `sudo update-grub` command; You should see some output with list of Linux distributions found on each partitions

**Step 3:** When finished, close the **Terminal** and reboot your machine.

Now enter into **GRUB** boot menu again and you should be able to see Elementary Freya being listed together with Ubuntu 14.04.

That's it.

**Comments to your questions**

> So is there any way I can fix this? Or just try reinstalling Elementary? Please tell me with details which partitions I should choose.

Reinstallation may be risky, since you multi-boot with Windows. Not sure how far Windows-Linux coexistence had improved since XP, but I had more failures than successes back then. Regarding my experience of failures, you may read **Side notes** at bottom.

> As you can see, /dev/sda8 was formatted; it's where Freya was installed. By the way, do I need to define another swap partition for Elementary? Or it will use the same one Ubuntu does?

The installation is most likely default, since there is only one partition being mentioned by you.

By default, Elementary (or Ubuntu) will auto-detect your amount of main memory or **RAM** and set up the **SWAP** size by itself. It's automatically set up by the installer so you can forget about it.

For advanced installation, choosing "Something else" option in the installer will allow you to set the amount of `/`, `/swap` and `/home` on different partitions. If you don't know what are these, you can just ignore (This will pull [another long answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/343352), or you can just google this out).

> For the "boot loader installation device location" I chose `/dev/sda8`. Maybe this is the problem: I chose that instead of just `/dev/sda`.

No, your made a good decision here.

For a machine having multiple Linux distributions on the same hard disk, the boot loader should be installed to the same partition where the new Linux distribution would be installed (or don't install the new boot loader). Then, always use the existing boot loader.

The existing boot loader, **GRUB**, is the default boot loader for Ubuntu. So if you had installed any Linux distribution after that, boot into Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` to tell **GRUB** of the changes made to the hard disk.

If, let's say, Elementary Freya is *the only* operating system on the hard disk of your machine (and no other Linux, Windows or Mac), then you should be choosing `/dev/sda` instead.

> I say "any" boot menu because there are two: first the one for Windows 8 pops up, with this OS as its only option, and if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, GRUB pops up, with Ubuntu, elementary OS Luna and two more options.

In your case, you have two bootloaders: Windows boot loader and GRUB. It seems that your Windows boot loader is chainloading the GRUB boot loader.

On second thought, I see like this: Windows boot loader being the first to be loaded, but when escaped, it falls back to GRUB boot loader being the second in line. Those two boot loaders may be loaded sequentially by the BIOS, although I'm not sure if this possible (ask someone else for this).

In fact, it is possible to use Windows boot loader to detect Linux distribution which has been explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/499617/how-can-i-add-linux-to-the-new-windows-8-boot-manager) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader) (See **Disclaimer** at most bottom).

> Or in the other way I can look at it, if I had chosen `/dev/sda` instead that means it will create a partition for the boot loader and no problem.

Choosing `/dev/sda` means that the boot loader will be installed to **Master Boot Record (MBR)**, the first sector of a hard disk. It won't create any additional partition.

So if you view the partitions in a partition editor such as **GParted** or **Gnome Disk Utility**, you won't find any other partiton than `/` (root) for a default, single Linux distro installation.

**Side notes**

My worst experience was when I set up dual-boot Windows XP and Ubuntu on two different laptops with different hardware configuration. I "successfully" bricked (permanently damaged) Wi-Fi adapter card, twice. Both machines. Since then, I vow to never dual-boot with Windows again.

**Disclaimer**

I quote the links to prove the possiblilties of using Windows boot loader (and without using GRUB at all), but *not* for recommendation. After all, your existing set up is working well regardless of how you did it. There is no reason to change the set up, unless updating GRUB didn't work for you.